# Memoir chapter headings

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

I'm using memoir class and I would like to know if it's possible to change the heading name of a specific chapter because the chapter title is too long and it's not well displayed as a heading in each page, only in the main chapter title.
I mean, I want this title to appear on the top of each page

'Capítulo  2  Influencia de las IDM en el espectro de ondas de espín'

and as a chapter title, that appears this

'Capítulo  2 Influencia de las Interacciones de Dzyaloshinskii-Moriya en el espectro de ondas de espín'

(I'm writing in spanish)

Thanks beforehand,
Dave

Comment: You can write `\chapter[Short title for headings]{Long, rambling chapter title to fill up the first page (hopefully)}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the same as the standard classes, you can go

```
\chapter[short]{long}
```

and the short form is used in headers and table of contents.

Comment: I assume so but I know nothing of lyx.

Comment: For what it's worth, `memoir` gives you up to two optional arguments: `\chapter[<ToC entry>][<header entry>]{<chapter title>}`.  Otherwise, the `[short]` is used for both headers and the ToC.

Comment: Oh, thanks. In LyX it's just to put that command in an ERT box.